# R Shiny plot_ly update histogram type

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, histogram

I think I have a very basic question but I couldn't find any similar questions asked either here on Google, hence I thought to ask.
I have an R Shiny app and I create histogram based on some data received from a database. For simplicity, this is the code I have to create my histogram plot:

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = as.character(mtcars$gear),
                   type = "histogram",
                   histnorm = "percent",
                   alpha = 0.8) %>%
           layout(title = "Distrib")
```

the user has the ability to change on the fly the histogram type from "percent" to "" (meaning, normal count).
How can I now update the "fig" object without querying again the database and building a new plot from scratch?
I was thinking perhaps there's something like

```
fig %>% update(histnorm ='')
```

but that doesn't seem to be the case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `histnorm` field from the definition of the figure:

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = as.character(mtcars$gear),
                   type = "histogram",
                   alpha = 0.8)
```

Then, on the fly, you can specify `fig <- fig %>% layout(histnorm = "percent")` when the user selects the type "percent". When the user selects "normal count", you just recall `fig` (since the default for `histnorm` is "normal count").

Comment: Right, but my issue is how to update an already existing plot object stored in variable "fig"

Comment: It gives the error message " 'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'histnorm'"